# Line-wise refactoring in Lisps

Tags: vim, scheme

Scheme (for example in the SICP book) usually follows this indentation model:

```
(define (abs n)   
  (cond ((> n 0) n)
        ((< n 0) (- 0 n))
        (else 0)))
```

I find it difficult to refactor code with this structure because in many other languages the convention is to isolate analogue constructs on different lines, for example:

```
if (n > 0) {
    return n;
} else if {
    return -n;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

So the `else` can be removed by deleting the third and second last lines (e.g. in Vi with `d2d`).

I am wondering how refactorings of this kind can be efficiently performed on Scheme code when they impact the last line, which is full of `)` characters?

Comment: Look for “go to matching parenthesis”, or “cut sexp starting/ending at current parenthesis” in your editor. In Emacs the former is bound to C-M-b, C-M-f, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Move to that line.
2. `da(` to "`d`elete `a`round `(`", making the result

   ```
   (define (abs n)
     (cond ((> n 0) n)
           ((< n 0) (- 0 n))
           ))
   ```
3. `kJ` to move up a line and join this line with the next line, resulting in

   ```
   (define (abs n)
     (cond ((> n 0) n)
           ((< n 0) (- 0 n))))
   ```

So, for your example, this would be `Gda(kJ`:

[image: mini screencast]

Comment: Wow, Vim gifs? Nice. Is there a site for making those?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I used a tool I wrote called [`mkcast`, available on Github](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/mkcast).

Answer (score 2):

I use [`paredit`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) to structurally edit Lisp code (which lets you can deal with s-expressions rather than potentially ambiguous units like lines). There seems to be an equivalent [`vim` version](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3998) (also [mirrored](https://github.com/vim-scripts/paredit.vim) on `github`) that I can't really comment on because I've never used it.